# How to make transition from bottom to top

Tags: html, css

I want to make the title and the content to move up to the right position on hover.

The problem is that the transition on the `Title` class doesn't work and the hover effect doesn't work as well.

What i tried to do is to change the hover so that when i hover over the `ImageText` class, both the Title and Content go to `top: 0;` and `postion: relative;`
and this works but the transtion doesn't work.
But the problem here is that i should not hover over ImageText. What I should  hover over is the `Title` class however when I  try this, the transition doesn't work.

```css
.Section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}

.Column2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.two {
  grid-row: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 2fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
}

.ImageText {
  position: relative;
  background-size: 100%;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  height: 100%;
}

.Title:hover+.Content {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.Content:hover {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}


/* .Title:hover {
          position: relative;
          top: 0;
        } */

.Content:hover+.Title {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.Title {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font: caption;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.Content {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="Section">

  <div class="Column2">

    <div class="two">

      <div class="ImageText" style="background-image:url(https://i.ibb.co/6Rvr53T/1.jpg)">

        <div class="Title">
          SpaceX's Next Starship Prototype Taking Shape
        </div>

        <div Class="Content">
          Construction of the test craft is proceeding apace, as two new photos posted on Twitter today (Sept. 17) by company founder and CEO Elon Musk reveal.
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="ImageText" style="background-image:url(https://i.ibb.co/F87mkdk/3.jpg)">

        <div class="Title">
          NASA's Juno Mission Cheks Out Eclipse on Jupiter
        </div>

        <div Class="Content">
          All is well on our largest neighbor; NASA's Juno spacecraft just managed to spot the shadow of Jupiter's moon, Io, passing over its marbled clouds.
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="ImageText" style="background-image:url(https://i.ibb.co/yRMWZQ5/4.jpg)">

        <div class="Title">
          Europe Wants Ideas for Cave-Spelumking Moon Robots
        </div>

        <div Class="Content">
          As NASA makes a big push to land humans on the moon's surface by 2024, the European Space Agency (ESA) wants to learn more about the lunar caves that lie beneath.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result should be, when you hover over the Title,  both the Title and the Content should go up to `top:0;` and this effect should have `transtion:0.5s;`

The solution should be with CSS not JavaScript.

It is better to go to full page when running the code snippet so that you have better visualisation of the problem.

Comment: Upload your CSS code or make a code snippet for further review. Also you can use [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: the css is after the html just scroll down

Comment: I see, but you must make a code snippet !

Comment: @Mohammad try this now

Answer (score 0):

Try this or smth like that.
Put the Content blocks in the Title blocks.

```css
    .Section {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
      transform: translateY(30px);
    }
    
    .Column2 {
      grid-column: 2;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px;
      grid-gap: 1em;
    }
    
    .two {
      grid-row: 2;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 2fr;
      grid-column-gap: 1em;
    }
    
    .ImageText {
      position: relative;
      background-size: 100%;
      color: white;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .Title {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      font: caption;
      position: absolute;      
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;   
    }
    
    .Title .Content {        
        max-height: 0;
        transition: max-height 0.25s;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .Title:hover .Content {      
      max-height: 500px;
      transition: max-height 0.5s;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Style.css" />
</head>

<body>


<div class="Section">

<div class="Column2">

  <div class="two">

    <div class="ImageText" style="background-image:url(https://thenypost.files.wordpress.com/2019/09/ap_19265088288587.jpg)">
        <div class="Title">
          SpaceX's Next Starship Prototype Taking Shape
          <div class="Content">
                Construction of the test craft is proceeding apace, as two new photos posted on Twitter today (Sept. 17) by
                company founder and CEO Elon Musk reveal.
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ImageText" style="background-image:url(https://thenypost.files.wordpress.com/2019/09/ap_19265088288587.jpg)">

      <div class="Title">
        NASA's Juno Mission Cheks Out Eclipse on Jupiter
        <div Class="Content">
            All is well on our largest neighbor; NASA's Juno spacecraft just managed to spot the shadow of Jupiter's
            moon, Io,
            passing over its marbled clouds.
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>

    <div class="ImageText" style="background-image:url(https://thenypost.files.wordpress.com/2019/09/ap_19265088288587.jpg)">

      <div class="Title">
        Europe Wants Ideas for Cave-Spelumking Moon Robots
        <div Class="Content">
            As NASA makes a big push to land humans on the moon's surface by 2024, the European Space Agency (ESA) wants
            to learn
            more about the lunar caves that lie beneath.
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your answear works but this is not waht im after. what im after i to make the title go top 'top:0;' so the black color cover the hole picture i tried your code and the problem is that the height of the content can be more the text height